# Parse .doc file (MS Word) in browser

Tags: javascript, ms-word

Is there any way to parse (extract text from) a `.doc` file in the browser using Javascript?
I've searched a lot for libraries - but they only seem to work with `.docX`..

Answer (score 1):

Unlike .docx, .doc is a proprietary binary format. Microsoft's documentation is here: [Word (.doc) Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-doc/ccd7b486-7881-484c-a137-51170af7cc22). Most likely you would be targeting the **WordDocument** stream, as mentioned on page 28 of the documentation.

It might be faster to simply upsave the .doc files to .docx, then extract the text from them.

Comment: hmm... do you know how to do that programmatically?

Comment: I tried a couple of times in the 90s, but Microsoft hadn't published the spec back then. The learning curve is very steep for a rather small reward.

Comment: I meant, how to do the 'upsave the .doc files to .docx' part? with JS\Node

Comment: Open the .doc file in Word and save it as .docx. This can be automated with VBA if you have many files. Then process the .docx files.